# Inscribe Grid in Circle of Specific Size

Tags: grid-layouts

I'm an avid hunter and shooter. I want to use Mathematica to create a circular dope card that fits within my scope cap. Here's an example:

[image]

Here's some sample data of a 6.5 Creedmoor shooting a 140gr bullet out to 500 yards in a 10 mph crosswind.

```
data = {{"Range", "Elevation", "Windage", "Time"}, {0, "--", "--", 
    0}, {100, -1.8, 0.3, 0.11}, {200, 0, 0.6, 0.25}, {300, 2.4, 0.9, 
    0.36}, {400, 5.2, 1.2, 0.5}, {500, 8.3, 1.5, 0.64}};

Grid[data, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, without manually specifying all locations of lines and text boxes, is there:

1. A way to inscribe a grid of data in a circle?
2. A way to specify this to a specific size? Say 40mm in diameter.

I would want to create several of these for different rifles, calibers, and loads so automation would be very helpful here.

Comment: (pedant) You want to *inscribe* the grid in the circle; or, circumscribe a circle *around* the grid. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Crap. INSCRIBE!

Answer (score 3):

I was hoping someone would have a great quick way to *inscribe* a grid. Here's my semi-automated way of achieving the same thing.

First, our ballistics input:

```
data = {{100, -1.8, 0.3, 0.11}, {200, 0.0, 0.6, 0.25}, {300, 2.4, 0.9,
     0.36}, {400, 5.2, 1.2, 0.5}, {500, 8.3, 1.5, 0.64}, {600, 11.9, 
    3.5, 0.79}, {700, 15.6, 4.1, 0.96}, {800, 19.7, 4.8, 1.13}, {900, 
    24.2, 5.6, 1.32}, {1000, 29.2, 6.3, 1.51}, {1100, 34.7, 7.1, 
    1.73}, {1200, 40.7, 7.9, 1.95}};
description = "CT Edge 6.5 Creedmoor 1:8 143 gr 2710 fps";
```

Now, to build the dope card.

```
DynamicModule[{cs = 10, len, b = 6.5, dpx, dpy, 
  labels = {"DIST", "ELEV", "WIND", "TIME", "ELEV", "WIND", "TIME", "DIST"},format},
 dpx = Subdivide[b, 0, 3];
 dpy = Subdivide[5.5, -5.5, Min[7, len + 1]];
 format = data;
 format[[All, 1]] = Round[format[[All, 1]]];
 format = 
  format /. 
   r : {d_, e : 0 | 0., w_, t_} :> (Style[#, Bold, Underlined] & /@ r);
 format = 
  format /. 
   r : {d_, e_, w_, t_} :> (Style[#, 12] & /@ {d, PaddedForm[e, {2, 1}], 
       PaddedForm[w, {2, 1}], PaddedForm[t, {3, 2}]});
 len = Length@format;
 Dynamic@Graphics[{
    Circle[{0, 0}, cs],
    Text[Style["Setup", 11, Underlined, Bold], {0, cs - 1}],
    Text[Style["YARDS/MOA", 12, Bold], {0, -cs + 2}],
    Inset[
     Row[{Style[description, 12]}, ImageSize -> 200, 
      Alignment -> {Center, Center}], {0, cs - 2.5}],
    {CapForm["Butt"], Line[posy[#, cs] & /@ dpy]},
    {CapForm["Butt"], Line[{{#, -5.5}, {#, 5.5}} & /@ Subdivide[b, -b, 6]]},
    {Thickness[0.01], CapForm["Butt"], Line[{{0, -5.5}, {0, 5.5}}]},
    Text[#[[1]], {#[[2]] - b/6, Mean[dpy[[;; 2]]]}, {0, 0}] & /@Thread[{labels[[;; 4]], -dpx}],
    Text[#[[1]], {#[[2]] + b/6, Mean[dpy[[;; 2]]]}, {0, 0}] & /@ 
     Thread[{Reverse@labels[[-4 ;;]], dpx}],
    (*First column*)
    With[{fc = Take[format, UpTo[6]]},
     Text[#[[1]], #[[2]], {0, 0}] & /@ 
      Thread[{Flatten[fc], 
        Reverse /@ 
         Tuples[{MovingAverage[Rest[dpy], 2], -dpx - b/6}]}]
     ],
    (*Second column*)
    If[len > 6,
     With[{sc = Take[format, {7, UpTo[12]}]},
      Text[#[[1]], #[[2]], {0, 0}] & /@ 
       Thread[{Flatten[RotateLeft /@ sc], 
         Reverse /@ 
          Tuples[{Take[MovingAverage[Rest[dpy], 2], Length[sc]], 
            Reverse[dpx + b/6]}]}]
      ], Nothing]

    }, PlotRangePadding -> None
   ], Initialization :> (posy[y_, cs_] := {{#, y}, {-#, y}} &@
     Sqrt[(cs^2 - y^2)])
 ]
```

And our output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, to resize for printing. My scope cap was 1.8".

```
With[{dia = 1.8}, Rasterize[%, RasterSize -> dia*72*4, ImageSize -> dia*72]]
```

And the final product:

[image]